# How do I fix gradle in Flutter?

Tags: gradle, flutter

I get this error running my project:

> - Error running Gradle:
>     ProcessException: Process
>
>   "/Users/jacobgjrva/AndroidStudioProjects/stage_me/android/gradlew" 
>     exited abnormally:
>
>   Command: 
>     /Users/jacobgjrva/AndroidStudioProjects/stage_me/android/gradlew 
>     app:properties
>
>   Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in 
>     the android/ folder.

Do anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
}
```

Comment: are you trying to integrate flutter into an existing project or is it standalone?

Comment: Yepp it is standalone

Comment: Having the same issue as well

Answer (score 0):

Run the `gradlew` command with `--stacktrace` for details of the error.

Also check the `build.gradle` file.
In the block reported in the answer there are `{ }` in the wrong place.

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }
}   //it is missing in your code
```

And:

```
   task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
}// You have to remove this.
```